# Unable to cast from CommPort to SerialPort

Tags: java, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with my com ports in java. However i am repeatedly getting an error when i am trying to cast comm port to serial port.It says cannot cast from CommPort to SerialPort. Then how am i supposed to open the port so that i can recieve data.Can anyone help?

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

public class connectnow implements Runnable,SerialPortEventListener {

    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

    InputStream inputStream;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    Thread readThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println("portList=" + portList);

        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier)portList.nextElement();
            System.out.println("portId=" + portId);

        }
    }

    connectnow()
    { try {
        System.out.println("In contructor");
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp1111",500);// here is the issue
        System.out.println(" Serial Port.. " + serialPort);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println("Port in use Exception");
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(" Input Stream... " + inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener((javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener) this);

    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        System.out.println("Tooo many Listener exception");
    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {

        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // no handshaking or other flow control
        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

        // timer on any read of the serial port
        serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(500);

        System.out.println("................");

    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        System.out.println("UnSupported comm operation");
    }
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();}
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("In run() function ");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            // System.out.println();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception in run() method");
        }
    }
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
        try{
        if(ev.getEventType()==SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
        {
            System.out.println("usha");
        }

        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {

        }
         if(ev.getEventType()== SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
         {
         System.out.println("abxxx");   
         }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort is a subclasse of CommPort. Unless you know for a fact that the variable declared as CommPort contains a SerialPort instance, your cast will compile correctly but fail at run time with an invalid cast exception. Indeed, casting a variable to its subclass is always valid at compile time but casting an instance of a class to an instance of a subclass is not valid and will fail at run time.
[EDIT]
From the documentation, it appears that the returned objects from getPortIdentifiers are instances of either SerialPort or ParallelPort. Accordingly the cast ti SerialPort will work provided the returned object is indeed a SerialPort and not a ParallelPort. Add an if statement to ensure you are getting a SerialPort instance and not something else. To do that, you can use getPortType method. See [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html#getPortType()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html#getPortType%28%29)
Instead of picking up the last serial port in the list, you may want to check the name of the port using getName() or use a file descriptor to open a specific port.

```
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier)portList.nextElement();
        System.out.println("portId=" + portId);
         if (portId.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                break;
    }
```

Comment: okay i got you. can you please suggest me an alternative to opening the port as opposed to the one i am already using?

Comment: i replaced that line( the one which says the issue is herein the comments) with  portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); but now i cant use the serialport event because there is nothing in my serial port

Comment: can you please explain this i am working with rxtx and ports for the first time hence it takes time for me to grasp. How can i resolve the issue @EJP

Comment: See updated answer. Note that you may also want to check the port name to ensure that it is the correct port (assuming you have more than one serial port connected to your machine)

Comment: @EJP See clarified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under macOS, another way to get

```
error: incompatible types: CommPort cannot be converted to SerialPort
```

is if /Library/Java/Extensions/RXTXcomm.jar exists, but you are trying to use a [nrjavaserial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) jar file.

One way to diagnose this is to compile using `javac -verbose` and look for where the definition of CommPort is coming from.

If you have

```
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/Library/Java/Extensions/RXTXcomm.jar(gnu/io/CommPortIdentifier.class)]]
```

Then CommPort.class is coming from /Library/Java/Extensions/RXTXcomm.jar, which is probably not what you want if you are trying to use nrjavaserial.

Instead, you want to see something like:

```
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/Users/yourid/foo/barlib/nrjavaserial-3.11.0.devel.jar(gnu/io/CommPort.class)]]
```